# Can't change sensitivity of touchpad on Dell Vostro 5468

Tags: touchpad, dell

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Vostro 5468 and the touchpad tap is too sensitive and practically useless when I write text.

I tried to adjust the sensitivity using:

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Synaptics Finger" 90 100 255
```

But no matter what values I choose for the sensitivity, nothing changes, and it remains hypersensitive.

In fact, xinput reports two entries for touchpad:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ Logitech MX Anywhere 2                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ DELL0785:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

It seems only the DELL one is active because if I disable it with `xinput --disable 12`, the touchpad stops working, but if I disable the synaptics touchpad  (15) it still works. But no matter what I do (I tried to change the "Synaptics Finger" setting for both) nothing happens.

I can change other properties of the touchpad (12), like Tap Action and Synaptics Off. But Finger, nope.

Is there anything else that might control the tap sensitivity of that touchpad and override xinput? Is Synaptic Finger controlling the tap sensitivity in the first place? Or have I misunderstood something?

The machine is dual booting Windows & Ubuntu, and the touchpad works perfectly well in Windows.

I would really appreciate any help to solve this, since I use my computer a lot for typing texts.